# Grouping Table rows without access to the HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am currently trying to make a table responsive , but due to how the table rows are setup the table does not display correctly in the responsive design.

The way to solve this issue would be the ability to group some of the tables rows together.

The problem is that I dont have access to the HTML used to create the table. Is there a way to this without changing the html ?

Thanks

Colin

Comment: How do you want to group them? References to groups of rows?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit ? What is the result that  you want exactly ?